# Why doesn't voltage increase when the wire length increases; there's more work to be done?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electricity, potential-energy, voltage

[This Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/308627/why-doesnt-potential-difference-across-circuit-increase-when-length-of-wire-inc) did not answer my question.

The voltage of a circuit is the difference in each Coulombs potential energy at the negative pole, compared to the positive pole. At the negative pole, there's a whole wire for the electrons to pass through under the influence of the Coulombic forces; a whole wire with atoms between which they can accelerate, before transmitting their kinetic energy into the atoms.

The longer the wire, the more durations of acceleration (thus, the more kinetic energy is produced). But, the longer the wire, the more resistance there is, thus, the lower the amperage. A lower amperage means less acceleration between each collision (assuming constant wire diameter). So, as the wire gets longer, there's more durations of acceleration, but the acceleration is lower. The accepted answer to [this Q](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489505/does-increasing-the-length-of-wire-increase-the-work-energy-needed-to-move-ele?rq=1) claims that this is the explanation.

But I doubt these two factors cancel each other out such as to leave the voltage unchanged with change in wire length. That is, despite this, I still think a longer wire would mean more kinetic energy is produced. More kinetic energy means there must have been more potential energy that was transmitted into it; thus, the voltage must have been higher. But it isn't, so what gives?

There's the distance factor; the longer the wire, the further away from the charged poles of the battery the electrons get. However, this would then make the voltage dependent on how close you lay the wire to the poles, which is again contrary to the assertion that the voltage only depends on the battery.

Comment: The link is to somewhere else than an actual answer.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thanks, fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The longer the wire, the more durations of acceleration (thus, the more kinetic energy is produced).

> a whole wire with atoms between which they can accelerate, before transmitting their kinetic energy into the atoms.

This immediately shows where the crux of your problem is. You are mistaking lengths, time, acceleration, forces, all into one big mess, and it is mixed into the standard classical atomic Drude model of metals. That model simply asserts that a metal would have mostly free, sea of (valence) electrons, in which mostly immobile ions stand still and vibrate.

The important lesson to learn about the *classical atomic Drude model* is that this is a **dead end.** Several decades of many of the best minds in physics were wasted trying to figure out what would be the correct method to approximate the flow of pinballs through pegs that this model entails, before we realised that the quantum theory requires that electron waves of the allowed types will essentially think that the lattice is just not there, and **essentially pass through uninhibited.**

---

> So, as the wire gets longer, there's more durations of acceleration, but the acceleration is lower. The accepted answer to this Q claims that this is the explanation.

This is correct, but you are not convinced. That is because you are not using enough maths to help you reason this through.

> There's the distance factor; the longer the wire, the further away from the charged poles of the battery the electrons get. However, this would then make the voltage dependent on how close you lay the wire to the poles

To help make sense of why you are wrong here, it helps to bring in what you said earlier:

> The voltage of a circuit is the difference in each Coulombs potential energy at the negative pole, compared to the positive pole.

A modern physicist would not be happy with saying "each Coulomb's potential energy at...", but that is a nitpick compared to the serious issue that you are having here.

The battery sets up a certain voltage $V$, and that represents the total amount of potential energy that is available for the wire to convert into kinetic energy. Namely, in a certain time interval $t$, the total amount of battery's chemical potential energy converted into heat, i.e. the kinetic energy of the random type, of the ions, is $IVt=\frac{V^2t}R$, the latter of which is true due to converting the former by Ohm's Law. Now, as you correctly reasoned in

> But, the longer the wire, the more resistance there is, thus, the lower the amperage. A lower amperage means less acceleration between each collision (assuming constant wire diameter).

This means that the total amount of energy converted into heat is actually less when the wire is longer, in direct contradiction to your statements

> The longer the wire, the more durations of acceleration (thus, the more kinetic energy is produced).

> That is, despite this, I still think a longer wire would mean more kinetic energy is produced.

The reason why these are wrong, is because you have neglected to consider the problem in greater detail (in addition to more confusion in the things to be considered). It is known that, to a ridiculously remarkable agreement between experiment and theory, that the resistance $R$ of a wire is given by $R=\rho\frac\ell A$, where $\ell$ is the length of the wire, $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the wire in which the current flows, and $\rho$ is the resistivity of the material used; the geometry of the problem is factorised out of $\rho$, and thus we can tabulate this quantity in handbooks, one value for each material we might want to use.

That means, Ohm's Law that you should be familiar with, starts as
$$
\begin{align}
\tag1V&=IR\\
\tag2V&=I\rho\frac\ell A\\
\tag3\frac V\ell&=\rho\frac I A\\
\tag4E&=\rho J
\end  {align}
$$
where we define $E=V/\ell$ and $J=I/A$ are the electric field and the current density. This particular equation is typically recast using the definition of conductivity $\sigma=1/\rho$ so as to write Ohm's Law as $J=\sigma E$, but the physical content is not changed.

Now, when you want to talk about forces, the quantity that is closest is the electric field $E$; In N2L: $\sum F=\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dt}=ma$ that you are familiar with, the Abraham-Lorentz force law without magnetism is $F=qE$, and so you should see that what I am saying is true. From $E=V/\ell$, then, it is clear that the forces, and thus also the accelerations, for the electrons in between collisions with ions, assuming that this proven-false picture is valid at all, has been reduced due to increasing the length $\ell$ of the wire. The result must be that the electrons **cannot be getting more kinetic energy this way.**

At the same time, by having the correct picture of what is happening, you will be able to see that your statement here is false:

> However, this would then make the voltage dependent on how close you lay the wire to the poles

namely, it is the electric field $E$ that is dependent upon the length of the wire, not the voltage.

Comment: "This means that the total amount of energy converted into heat is actually less when the wire is longer, in direct contradiction to your statements." What I meant to say was, "the more kinetic energy is produced per Coulomb", which would mean the voltage is higher, since it is the difference in potential energy per Coulomb between two points. But of course, there are less Coulombs per second (due to the higher resistance), so the amount of total kinetic energy produced could be less.

Comment: "the more kinetic energy is produced per Coulomb", yes, this means that the voltage is higher, but it is not what is happening in reality. In reality, it is that when you have a longer wire, the same battery voltage is divided over more inter-ionic gaps, thus it is that less kinetic energy is produced per Coulomb, less voltage per inter-ionic gap. The electric field is smaller. It is that this smaller inter-ionic gap voltage, this smaller electric field, that is causing the current to drop, causing the less Coulombs per second. Your logical reasoning is in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

[Ohm discovered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) that for many conducting metarials, voltage and current (amperage) have a linear relation. Wires (typically made from copper or aluminum) mainly follow Ohm's law. Any given wire (given material, length and diameter) thus has a constant quotient of voltage to current, which we call its resistance.

Ohm does not tell us how that relates to the lower-level model of accelerating and colliding electrons. That model is much more complex (too complex for a short answer here) and can also explain the non-linear relation of voltage and current in semiconductors. Let's just state that in a given material, you need a stronger electrical field to make the electrons move faster on average, and that this turns out to be a linear relationship: double the electrical field, and the electrons will move twice as fast (accelerate more before they hit the next obstacle).

Electrical field in a wire can be seen as the voltage along the wire divided by its length (as its unit "volts per meter" implies).

Current can be understood as the number of electrons that pass through a given point (wire cross section) per time unit, so it could be given in electrons per second (1 Ampere is roughly 6250000000000000000 electrons per second). As the density of electrons in a wire is constant (given by the material), the current directly relates to the speed of the electrons. Double their speed, and twice as much of them will pass through a given point of the wire.

The electrons only "care about" the local environment, the electrical field that exists locally, no matter if that is caused by a low voltage over a short wire or a high voltage over a long one.

Now to your question:

With a longer wire (say: double length) and the same source (e.g. battery, providing the same voltage), you get half the electrical field, implying half the average electron speed, meaning half the current.

If you want the same current, you need the same electrical field, meaning twice the original voltage.

This is in line with the "resistance" model. If you call the resistance of the original wire R, then a wire of twice the length can be seen as as series connection of two R resistors, giving the addition of their resistances: 2R.

If you want to view it from potential energy: If we keep the voltage (initial potential energy of the electron at the negative pole) and double the wire length, then (in a simplified, flawed model) every electron has twice as many collisions, meaning that between the collisions it can only gather half the energy, and thus will on average move slower. The model is flawed as it would imply a square-root relation, which is contradicted by experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage at the ends of a conductor changes as the resistance of that conductor changes.

To some approximation, a battery can be represented as a source of emf $E$ with internal resistance $r$. Then for a conductor with resistance $R$ the current will be $$I = \frac E {R + r},$$ and voltage $$V = IR = \frac R {R + r} E.$$ So, $V$ is a monotonically increasing function of $R$.

However, the internal resistance of batteries is quite small, so although the voltage increases with increasing resistance, it does so slowly and within the limit $r=0$ we will have $V=\operatorname{const}$.

Comment: This has very little to do with the OP's question.